# MySQL Performance Schema cannot be upgraded

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I recently upgraded MySQL Workbench on my Windows server to 6.2. Prior to the upgrade, I had Performance Reports working fine.

Now since the upgrade it shows the following message when I try to go to Performance Reports or Performance Schema Setup:

> Performance Schema helper schema (sys) is outdated.
> MySQL Workbench needs to upgrade it.
> (current version is 1.1.0, server has 1.0.0).

There is a button for "Install Helper".  However when I click this button I receive the error:

> **Install sys Schema**
>
> Error installing sys Schema.
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Based on searches for others having the same issue I have tried a number of things, including ensuring that root@localhost has access to the sys schema (I checked just by using command line to connect to MySQL using that user and selecting from the tables), and also tried setting the root username and password in the my.ini file:

```
[client]
no-beep
user=root
password=xxxxx

[mysql]
user=root
password=xxxxx
```

Did a MySQL service restart and no difference.

Any suggestions please?